# Set simple parameterization for a json_value query (without using plan guides)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, json, simple-parameterization

I'm trying to run this query, but it fails it fails with:

> The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal.`

```
select  mt.pk           
from    My_Table mt    
where   json_value(mt.json_data, '$.group_id') != ''
```

As you can see, my parameter 2 **is** a string literal. The error is due a [bug in SQL Server 2016](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/36160774-json-value-clashes-with-forced-parameterization-on), when forced parameterization is on for the database.

I have confirmed that forced parameterization is turned on in my database, using:

```
select name, is_parameterization_forced from sys.databases
```

I am generally aware that you can force simple parameterization by creating a plan guide, then using it for the query. However, reviewing [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/specify-query-parameterization-behavior-by-using-plan-guides), I think that may be too complicated for my actual situation. This is partly because in reality, these queries are be generated on the fly and it's not realistic to *also* generate plan guides for all of them.

Reviewing [Query Hint docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query), it says

> The PARAMETERIZATION query hint can only be specified inside a plan guide. It cannot be specified directly within a query.

Upgrading to SQL Server 2017 is also not currently viable. Turning off forced parameterization for these databases is also not viable.

I am thinking that if I can set simple parameterization on for the query or session, that would be a workaround. Is such a technique possible? Is there any other workaround?

I realize that looking for solutions with simple parameterization is a little bit [X/Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)...any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

So far I have collected the following workarounds:

1. Wrap the `json_value` function in a dummy subquery. For example,

   ```
    select  mt.pk    
    from    My_Table mt    
    where   (select json_value(mt.json_data, '$.group_id')) != ''
   ```
2. Per [David](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/126936/david-browne-microsoft)'s first suggestion, try "Optimize for Ad Hoc Workloads" instead of forced parameterization. I haven't tested this, but it's plausible since the problem is forced parameterization.
3. Per David's second suggestion, execute the SQL statement dynamically in another database, and reference the original db with 3 part naming. I have confirmed that this works. For example,

   ```
   exec tempdb.sys.sp_executesql 
     N'select * from TargetDB.dbo.t where json_value(doc, ''$.group_id'') = '''' '
   ```

Going cross database is clever. It does work, even though it's a massive hack. What's even more bizarre is that apparently that had a connection level side effect of some kind. I'm able to run the original query normally with `json_value` afterwards, but only in that tab of SSMS. Copy/paste the identical SQL to another tab, errors per original description. Bizarre. But, it is a bug area after all.

---

Anything that defeats forced parameterization for the statement will serve as a workaround. The elements that prevent it are listed in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide#ForcedParam). For example, adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, or introducing a test against a variable.

This bug is still not fixed in SQL Server 2016 SP2-CU17 build 13.0.5888.